# How can I make a web-page preview

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe, preview

I'd like to place a modal window with a description of an external page. But to give the user more information about the page he about to visit I'd like to provide him with a page preview.

I can see the following ways:

- render a page with tools like CutyCapt - not working on my hosting :(
- make the screenshot with external recources (I found some - all not
  for free, I would try to find free tools)
- show the page as it is using something like `frame` (`frame` tag is not
  supported by HTML5).

My questions:

1. Is there any PHP tools to render a web page to PNG image not so
   demanding as CutyCapt is?
2. May be I missed any worthwhile online tool to render a page to an
   image?
3. I never used "frame" approach earlier so: is there any pros and cons to go deep into
   it? Am I right that HTML5 analog of `<frame>` tag is `<iframe>`?
4. Did I missed any other way to do my job?

Thanks!

Comment: 1) iframes are just inline frames - same concept, but more manageable in terms of where you can put them and what size they are. 2) PHP has the capability to take screenshots (Google it) but I recall some issues when I last tried it.

Comment: If you use an `(i)frame` your user doesn't get a preview.. they are actually already on the page.

Answer (score 1):

I once had a function on a page of mine which would load a specific page using an `ajax-request` and [php-curl](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) functions and then would just dump all the contents in a dynamically created `<div>` (Although I agree that the `<iframe>` is a better choice for this). But at that time I could not really adjust its size which made it kind of clumsy.

Comment: Why would you not just use an `iframe` for it?

Comment: I would nowadays, that was a very old thing :-) Maybe I should include that in the answer.